# Why is my code does not loop when i run it?

Tags: python, visual-studio

so i made a small script that converts a youtube vidoe to an audio then downloads it but i have a small problem..

i want to loop my code and it wont break untill i close it . i want it to ask me again to enter new link

```
from pafy import new
link = input("Enter the video link: ")
video = new(link)
best = video.getbestaudio()
filename = best.download(filepath="C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\MP3 Downloader\\Downloads")
```

im a beginner to python and any feedback will help me :)

Comment: It probably won't loop because there is no loop

Comment: use a while True: loop each time take an input from the user and check if it is equal to "quit" ... if not execute the functionality of the code. if so, break from the loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use while loop as below to keep it continue

```
import time

while True:
    link = input("Enter the video link: ")
    video = new(link)
    best = video.getbestaudio()
    filename = best.download(filepath="C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\MP3 Downloader\\Downloads")
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add a loop if you want it to loop ;). For instance :

```
from pafy import new
from time import sleep

while 1 :
    link = input("Enter the video link: ")
    video = new(link)
    best = video.getbestaudio()
    filename = best.download(filepath="C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\MP3 Downloader\\Downloads")
    sleep(1)
```